# Python requests is slow and takes very long to complete HTTP or HTTPS request

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib3

When requesting a web resource or website or web service with the requests library, the request takes a long time to complete. The code looks similar to the following:

```py
import requests
requests.get("https://www.example.com/")
```

This request takes over 2 minutes (exactly 2 minutes 10 seconds) to complete! Why is it so slow and how can I fix it?

Comment: Does it take a similar amount of time in your browser?

Comment: Or the server is slow?

Comment: Thank you guys for your response. I have identified the problem in my case, but due to the odyssee that was my search for a solution, I wanted to provide SO with all possible problems that I checked on the way. Find my answer below and please tell me if it helped!

Answer (score 156, accepted):

There can be multiple possible solutions to this problem. There are a multitude of answers on StackOverflow for any of these, so I will try to combine them all to save you the hassle of searching for them.

In my search I have uncovered the following layers to this:

## First, try logging

For many problems, activating logging can help you uncover what goes wrong ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16630836/5712053)):

```py
import requests
import logging

import http.client
http.client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1

# You must initialize logging, otherwise you'll not see debug output.
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log.propagate = True

requests.get("https://www.example.com")
```

In case the debug output does not help you solve the problem, read on.

#### If you only need to check if the server is up, try a HEAD or streaming request

It can be faster to not request all data, but to only send a HEAD request ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15780727/5712053)):

```py
requests.head("https://www.example.com")
```

Some servers don't support this, then you can try to stream the response ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15781814/5712053)):

```py
requests.get("https://www.example.com", stream=True)
```

#### For multiple requests in a row, try utilizing a Session

If you send multiple requests in a row, you can speed up the requests by utilizing a `requests.Session`. This makes sure the connection to the server stays open and configured and also persists cookies as a nice benefit. Try this ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60843169/5712053)):

```py
import requests
session = requests.Session()
for _ in range(10):
    session.get("https://www.example.com")
```

#### To parallelize your requests (try for > 10 requests), use requests-futures

If you send a very large number of requests at once, each request blocks execution. You can parallelize this utilizing, e.g., [requests-futures](https://github.com/ross/requests-futures) (idea from [kederrac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57736530/5712053)):

```py
from concurrent.futures import as_completed
from requests_futures.sessions import FuturesSession

with FuturesSession() as session:
    futures = [session.get("https://www.example.com") for _ in range(10)]
    for future in as_completed(futures):
        response = future.result()
```

Be careful not to overwhelm the server with too many requests at the same time.

If this also does not solve your problem, read on...

## The reason might not lie with requests, but the server or your connection

In many cases, the reason might lie with the server you are requesting from. First, verify this by requesting any other URL in the same fashion:

```py
requests.get("https://www.google.com")
```

If this works fine, you can focus your efforts on the following possible problems:

#### The server only allows specific user-agent strings

The server might specifically block `requests`, or they might utilize a whitelist, or some other reason. To send a nicer user-agent string, try this ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62028209/5712053)):

```py
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 12871.102.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.141 Safari/537.36"}
requests.get("https://www.example.com", headers=headers)
```

#### The server rate-limits you

If this problem only occurs sometimes, e.g. after a few requests, the server might be rate-limiting you. Check the response to see if it reads something along those lines (i.e. "rate limit reached", "work queue depth exceeded" or similar; [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48030775/5712053)).

Here, the solution is just to wait longer between requests, for example by using `time.sleep()`.

#### The server response is incorrectly formatted, leading to parsing problems

You can check this by not reading the response you receive from the server. If the code is still slow, this is not your problem, but if this fixed it, the problem might lie with parsing the response.

1. In case some headers are set incorrectly, this can lead to parsing errors which prevents chunked transfer ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31932308/5712053)).
2. In other cases, setting the encoding manually might resolve parsing problems ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48270114/5712053)).

To fix those, try:

```py
r = requests.get("https://www.example.com")
r.raw.chunked = True # Fix issue 1
r.encoding = 'utf-8' # Fix issue 2
print(response.text)
```

#### IPv6 does not work, but IPv4 does

This might be the worst problem of all to find. An easy, albeit weird, way to check this, is to add a `timeout` parameter as follows:

```py
requests.get("https://www.example.com/", timeout=5)
```

If this returns a *successful response*, the problem should lie with IPv6. The reason is that `requests` first tries an IPv6 connection. When that times out, it tries to connect via IPv4. By setting the timeout low, you force it to switch to IPv4 within a shorter amount of time.

Verify by utilizing, e.g., `wget` or `curl`:

```sh
wget --inet6-only https://www.example.com -O - > /dev/null
# or
curl --ipv6 -v https://www.example.com
```

In both cases, we force the tool to connect via IPv6 to isolate the issue. If this times out, try again forcing IPv4:

```sh
wget --inet4-only https://www.example.com -O - > /dev/null
# or
curl --ipv4 -v https://www.example.com
```

If this works fine, you have found your problem! But how to solve it, you ask?

1. A brute-force solution is to [disable IPv6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1676013/5712053) completely.
2. You may also [disable IPv6 for the current session](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/501082/362084) only.
3. You may just want to [force requests to use IPv4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46972341/5712053). (In the linked answer, you have to adapt the code to always return `socket.AF_INET` for IPv4.)
4. If you want to fix this problem for SSH, here is how to [force IPv4 for SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62106519/5712053). (In short, add `AddressFamily inet` to your SSH config.)
5. You may also want to check if the problem lies with your [DNS or TCP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56926067/5712053).

Comment: for me `timeout` fixed it even though `wget` and `curl` worked with IPv6. Modified https://stackoverflow.com/a/46972341/4339170 to force IPv4

Comment: That is wicked! Did you get to the bottom of it, what was the issue after all for you?

Comment: Having this problem with micropython's urequests what solved it was adding a header of {'Connection': 'Close'}. Some servers does not send a Content-Length or sends a wrong one. Telling it to close the connection, did solve my problem (10+ seconds to 1second)
https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib/issues/293

Comment: Great post! this worked for me (because requests was taking a lot of time to infer the charset):
r = requests.get("https://www.example.com")
r.raw.chunked = True # Fix issue 1
r.encoding = 'utf-8' # Fix issue 2

Comment: I had an issue with **IPv6 routing** and `timeout` fixed it

Comment: For those who are using VPN, try it without VPN.

Comment: In kde plasma you can disable IPV6 for a connection. This answer saved my skin!

Comment: the problem can be your DNS returning broken AAAA records (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8305.html#section-7.2)