# How can I analyze a slow request stemming from a long socket connection time from HttpClient?

Tags: c#, .net-core

On Ubuntu Jammy Jellyfish I have an application that is supposed to call a get on a specific address using `HttpClient` on dotnet sdk 7.0.

However the request takes and average of 131 seconds to complete. This is the code I am using in a console application to do the request:

```cs
var socketsHttpHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler();
socketsHttpHandler.ConnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
var httpClient = new HttpClient(socketsHttpHandler);
httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
var timer = new Stopwatch();
timer.Start();
var result = await httpClient.GetAsync(myUrl);
timer.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);

Console.WriteLine("Got response!");
Console.WriteLine(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

When I hit the same URL in my browser, it takes milliseconds. curl is also nearly instant. This is happening in all my dotnet applications. The code above was a minimal reproduction of the problem in order to find the source.

Calling any other URL works 100% with no delay, it just seems to be this specific endpoint.

When I set the connect timeout on the `SocketsHttpHandler` to 10 seconds it fails after 10 seconds, which seems to indicate the problem is occurring when trying to connect.

Other things I've tried:

- Manually loading in all my client certificates
- Disabling cookies
- Fiddling with proxy settings, however this url is in the bypass list and bypassed correctly via NO_PROXY env var and confirmed via the `HttpClient.DefaultProxy.IsBypassed()` method.

Additional Observations:

- Running in a docker container everything works and the response within 2 seconds
- Adding a second request causes the second request to succeed very quickly in less than a second after the first request hangs for 130 seconds. Might this be a connection in the `HttpConnectionPool`?

How can I analyze the problem to determine what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was related to IPV6. I disabled IPV6 on my network connection and things started working. IPV6 Connection is timing out after 130 seconds causing a massive delay and the TimeOut in HttpClient expires before that. This Answer gave me the info I needed because Python scripts were showing the same symptom.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62599037/178931