# Python API's running very slow (Google Sheet API and others)

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

This python code works well, but I takes 15 to 20 seconds:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account

# Setting credentials for accesing the google sheet
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'gsheet_key.json'
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)


# The ID and range of a sample spreadsheet.
SPREADSHEET_ID = "1tIO_doLRdML0oSvO81XXPI1eziwyqAZQhQ3qKP37HDs"
RANGE_NAME = "users!A1"

service = build("sheets", "v4", credentials = credentials)

# Call the Sheets API
sheet = service.spreadsheets()

result = (
  sheet.values()
  .get(spreadsheetId = SPREADSHEET_ID, range=RANGE_NAME)
  .execute()
)
values = result.get("values", [])
print(values)
```

Same for others APIs. Example: https://api.kanye.rest/: when running on the browser it took milliseconds, but in python code, 5 seconds approx.
The only way to speed it up, is to use the http alternative, or, when using requests, to set `verify=False`.

No solution placed in Stack Overflow solved the problem. Example:
[Python requests is slow and takes very long to complete HTTP or HTTPS request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62599036/python-requests-is-slow-and-takes-very-long-to-complete-http-or-https-request)